# How to format and unformat phone number in android

Tags: android

Im doing an application in android which needs to enter phone number in formatted way like `(xxx)xxx-xxx-x`.

I used code as

```
EditText inputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputfield);
inputField.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

Its working well.But when i click a button.,i need to get that phone number in normal format like `xxxxxxxxxx`.How could i do that?
Thanks.

Comment: it does it aumatically on my application : I give him a number as XX XX XX XX XX and he formats it as XXX-XXX-XXXX. otherwise,you probably have a class called something like phoneNumberFormat with the atribute you want

Comment: nope.For me.,when i click a button.,it takes number as (123)123-123-1.But i need as 1231231231.i need to remove tht brackets and all

Answer (score 7):

use

```
String number = inputNumber.replaceAll("\\D","");
```

> **Note:** \D matches a character that is not a digit

Comment: This  is right you may also want to call .toRegex() on your old value incase you are passing a regular expression instead of a string value

Answer (score 0):

if your number is in a string,you can use a String parser

```
String tel = (123)123-123-1

String tmp = tel.substring(tmp.indexOf("(")+1,tmp.indexOf(")"));
String[] result = tmp.split("-");
for(int i=0;i< result.size();i++){
   String tel= tel +result[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text in `xxxxxxxxx` form you can use a regEx:

```
String value = string.replaceAll("[0-9]","");
```